# Windows 8 start "metro" app from desktop app?

Tags: .net, windows-8

Is there any way to start a "Metro" app from a desktop app in .net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Modern UI apps have a URL protocol associated with them which can be used to launch the app.
You can find find the protocol for a specific app like this:

1. Press Windows+R
2. Type `regedit`
3. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId`
4. Find the subkey for your app (eg, `AMZNMobileLLC.KindleforWindows8_1.1.0.0_neutral__stfe6vwa9jnbp`)
5. Within that subkey, go to `ActivatableClassId_some long name_\CustomProperties`
6. The `Name` value will tell you the protocol name.

You can then pass  `name://` to `Process.Start()`.

(I answered this [on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/478975/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-to-a-windows-8-modern-ui-app/497213#497213))

Comment: Not all metro apps have a protocol association. This is dependent on the application owner.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way, to start win8 app from a win32 app.

1. In your WinRt project go to `Package.appxmanifest -> declarations`
2. Add `File Type Associations` and in `Name` field enter: `myAppLaunch`, in `File Type` enter `.myAppLaunch` (with dot)
3. Create a file (on the Descktop for e.g) and set `.myAppLaunch` as extension.
4. Now, in you Win32 app, execute that file.