# Launching a Metro-style app from a Desktop application

Tags: winapi, windows-8, desktop-application

Is there a way to launch windows 8 app from a desktop app? For e.g : In my desktop app I push some button, and my win8 app start(win8 app was in `Suspend` mode).

Comment: duplicate of [Windows 8 start "metro" app from desktop app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143341/windows-8-start-metro-app-from-desktop-app)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, using the [PackageManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx) and [IApplicationActivationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. See our [metro-driver](https://github.com/doo/metro-driver) project for some sample code.